# Is chrome cast sender app registration required for development for android?

Tags: android, chromecast

Is it necessary to register our chrome cast device before starting sender app for android  i only want to develop sender app for android not receiver app  please i want answer quick

Answer (score 1):

According to Google's Chromecast developer docs, you don't need to register your Chromecast device, but you'll **need to register your application**.

https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/registration

There's more information about Android sender apps in particular here:
https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender

Answer (score 1):

A long as you are using the Default Receiver, you do not need to register your app either. If you want to use the Styled Receiver or your own custom receiver, then an App Id is required and that requires you register your app.